# Using SPSS Propensity Score Matching yields Propensity Scores but no Match IDs

Tags: spss, propensity-scores, k-nearest-neighbour

I'm using the IBM provided PSM module in SPSS 26 on MacOS.

I have 1 group indicator and 4 covariates (3 scalar-1 nominal).

I tried match tolerances of 0.5 and 1.

I tried with and without replacement and with and without the performance toggle in the same menu (can't remember the exact name right now)

After these adjustments and upon running the module it creates another dataset with the additional propensity score and match id columns, as expected, but there are no matched id's so i can't sort or filter the dataset to create a nee dataset with only the matched cases from both groups.

What might be the problem?

My covariates have some missing values among them which might be a problem but i also think they wouldn't cause such a problem since propensity scores are already calculated, they are just not matched.